# useDispatch render unchanged childern

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, rerender

This is a functional component with a hook to Redux store to get products. Also, I defined `removeFromCart` hook to remove an item from the product list.

```js
const ProductListHooks = () => {
  const products = useSelector( state => state.productsModule.products);
  const removeFromCart = useDispatch({ type:actions.REMOVE_FROM_CART});
  return (
    <>
      {products.map(product => {
        return (
          <ProductItem
            product={product}
            key={product.id}
            removeFromCart={removeFromCart}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

**Problem:** When I call `removeFromCart` it removes the item but re-render all other items in the list. How can I fix it?

Comment: You can memoize the `ProductItem` component or implement a `shouldComponentUpdate()` for it that stops re-rendering if props haven't changed. You could also make `ProductItem` a pure component, but be aware of the implications of that (shallow props check each time)

Comment: @Jayce444 It is memoized and pure but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be pretty but you could memoize each item:

```
const ProductItem = function memo({ product, removeFromCart }) {
 return useMemo(() => 
       <Item product={product} removeFromCart={removeFromCart} />
    , [product]);

}
```